# MySQL - Get the latest record for a given list of column values

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have the following table structure:

Request table:

```
 id  insret_time             account id
 ------------------------------------
 1  2018-04-05 08:06:23       abc
 2  2018-09-03 08:14:45       abc
 3  2018-08-13 09:23:34       xyz
 4  2018-08-04 09:25:37       def
 5  2018-08-24 11:45:37       def
```

I need to find the latest records for account IDs abc and def. I don't care about xyz.

I tried to get the results using group by and inner join methods but was not successful in limiting the results to just the user list I care about.
Please advice

Update:
Thanks everyone for your feedback. Appreciate it! I needed the entire row as the output. I have used id column instead of timestamp to get the latest record since its auto-incremented This is what I finally came up with that gave me the output I need:

```
select t.* FROM table t
join (select max(table.id) as maxNum from table 
where account_id in ('abc','def') group by account_id) tm on t.id = tm.maxNum;
```

Comment: Just use `where` criteria with `group by` and `max`...

Comment: Show us what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you were looking for

```
  select account_id,max(insret_time)
  from table where account_id in ('abc', 'def')
  group by account_id
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `not in` and ignore `xyz` records and placing order by `desc`:

```
select account_id,max(insert_time) from table where account_id not in ('xyz') group by account_id order by id desc
```

Also you can use `!=` operators just for one expression:

```
select account_id,max(insert_time) from table where account_id!='xyz' group by account_id order by id desc
```

I hope it helps :)